# Fill missing value in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I 'm trying to fill missing values in spark dataframe using PySpark. But there is not any proper way to do it. My task is to fill the missing values of some rows with respect to their previous or following rows. Concretely , I would change the 0.0 value of one row to the value of the previous row, while doing nothing on a none-zero row . I did see the Window function in spark, but it only supports some simple operation like max, min, mean, which are not suitable for my case. It would be optimal if we could have a user defined function sliding over the given Window. 
Does anybody have a good idea ?

Comment: Please share example data, code you tried and expected output.

Comment: How would you define "the previous row"? Any sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Spark window API](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-windows.html) to access previous row data. If you work on time series data, see also [this package](http://sryza.github.io/spark-timeseries/0.3.0/index.html) for `missing data imputation`.

Comment: @wayag If the answer works for you, accept the answer :)